# Unit Testing - Use of Structuremap with MOQ

Tags: unit-testing, moq, structuremap

I want generic/oneline statements for structuremap configuration . please see the following code and suggest the changes :

**Structuremap configuration class :**

```
class StructureMapTestConfigurationRegistry : Registry
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DependencyConfigurationRegistry"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public StructureMapTestConfigurationRegistry()
        {

            For<Repository.IRepository<Report>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<Report>.RepositoryMockSetup());
            For<Repository.IRepository<RelatedContent>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<RelatedContent>.RepositoryMockSetup());
            For<Repository.IRepository<Tags>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<Tags>.RepositoryMockSetup());

            For<Repository.IRepository<ArticleTag>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<ArticleTag>.RepositoryMockSetup());
            For<Repository.IRepository<ReferenceBookTag>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<ReferenceBookTag>.RepositoryMockSetup());
            For<Repository.IRepository<EventsTag>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<EventsTag>.RepositoryMockSetup());
            For<Repository.IRepository<CountryFactfileTag>>().Use(MockObjectGenerator<CountryFactfileTag>.RepositoryMockSetup());
}
```

**BootStrapper Class :**

```
public static class TestBootstrapper
    {
        public static void TestConfigureStructureMap()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Container.Dispose();
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(o => o.AddRegistry(new StructureMapTestConfigurationRegistry()));
            ObjectFactory.Container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        }
}
```

**MockObjectGenerator Class :**

```
public static class MockObjectGenerator<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        private static List<TEntity> DummyTable
        {
            get
            {
                return MockEntities.GetData<TEntity>();
            }
        }

       public static IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryMockSetup()
        {
            Mock<IRepository<TEntity>> repository = new Mock<IRepository<TEntity>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            repository.Setup(o => o.Fetch(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>())).Returns((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> i) => DummyTable.Where(i.Compile()).ToList());
            repository.Setup(o => o.Create(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<TEntity>>())).Callback<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(items => DummyTable.AddRange(items));
            repository.Setup(o => o.Delete(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback<TEntity>(item => DummyTable.Remove(item));

}
}

**Mock Entities Class :**

public static class MockEntities
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, dynamic> MockData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

       public static void LoadData()
        {
            MockData.Add(typeof(CMSModel.Article).Name, ArticleTestData.GetTestRecords());
            MockData.Add(typeof(CMSModel.ArticleTag).Name, RelatedArticleContentTestData.GetTestRecords());
}

public static List<T> GetData<T>() where T : class
        {
            return (List<T>)MockData[typeof(T).Name];       
        }
}
```

**Note :**

This has been done so that in actual unit test , We dont have to write setup methods since that is done while creating dependent object using structuremap.

It works fine, but I want to refactor the configuration file code to generic

I have writen it for implentation like this :

```
 For(typeof(Repository.IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository.Repository<>));
```

is it possible for unit test configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though you'd need to specify all types entity types that are going to be used and pass them as Types. And you'll need to use non-generic version of functions (to be able to write For(type) instead of For). That way all your functions would work only on type variables and would look like simple methods.

Comment: can I write like this :

For<typeof(IRepository<>)>().Use(typeof(MockObjectGenerator<>.RepositoryMockSetup()));

Comment: No, you can't. You'd have to give up on generics and use usual for(type) to setup your mocks.